# CMOS differential pair - common-mode rejection ratio

Tags: cmos, differential

[image]

[image]

From: *Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits* by Behzad Razavi

This is a differential pair with a resistive load. The author derives the CMRR of the differential pair in the prescence of a g<sub>m</sub> mismatch between M<sub>1</sub> and M<sub>2</sub> and finite R<sub>SS</sub>. The result is Equation (4.58)

This equation suggests that if R<sub>SS</sub> were replaced with an ideal current source I<sub>SS</sub> that has infinite output resistance, then the CMRR should become infinite.

This does not make sense to me intuitively. If we assume that channel-length modulation and body effect are 0 and that M<sub>1</sub> has a higher g<sub>m</sub> than M<sub>2</sub> due to mismatch. Then, when the same V<sub>in, CM</sub> is applied to the gate of M<sub>1</sub> and M<sub>2</sub>, M<sub>1</sub> will demand a higher current from current source I<sub>SS</sub> and M<sub>2</sub> will receive a smaller current. Thus, the common-mode level at V<sub>out1</sub> will be lower than at of V<sub>out2</sub>, hence a differential gain due to CM input and thus a finite CMRR.

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember the ISS current is *constant*. With different gm's, the transistors may run different DC currents (which sum to ISS). Since you assume ISS is constant, and there are no body effects or ROUT effects, then when CM signal is applied, it doesn't change any of the currents (the mismatched currents remain mismatched), so the CM gain is 0.

Comment: You can't assume Iss is constant in the test for common mode gain with an Rss resistor.

Comment: Oh I see. So you are saying that for a certain Vin,CM value, M1 will have more ISS current than M2 and Vout1 will be slightly lower. However, increasing Vin,CM will just mean that Vs also increases by the same amount, so Vout does not respond to this Vin,CM change

Comment: exactly -- for a constant ISS. If there is an RSS, then you may have to make some assumptions about what is causing gm to differ between M1 and M2 -- Is it W/L, or VTH -- that could affect a CM calculation.

Comment: Thanks. Felt a little un intuitive at first.